# Getting children through id vs class in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I was using id to get children and now i changed to use class. Doing so what I find out is using class doesn't return the children.

Working code

```
//Don't remove first element of select box with id 'someSelectBox'    
$('#someSelectBox').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

Not working code

```
//Don't remove first element of ALL select box with class 'selectBoxClass'
$('.selectBoxClass').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

Can anyone explain why? And possible workout or alternative implementation idea.

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your markup? I have a feeling this isn't what you think it is

Comment: maybe it is a typo in your class name - can you show the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude the first `option` of each `select` element then you need to use the `.children('option:not(:first-child)')`
(*that is because you are targeting multiple `select` elements and `:first` only applies to the first of the whole set of results*)

Otherwise you only exclude the first `option` of the first `select` element.

---

The class should create no problems

```js
var options = $('.select-to-include').children('option:not(:first-child)');

options.css({color:'red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="select-to-include">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<select class="select-to-include">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```